# How to create a composs which always point to the location?

Tags: iphone, gps, xcode4.3

I am working on a project where i need to point a compass to a location.I need this compass always point to this location even if the user tilts the iphone or moves.I got the angle to the location and also the current heading.But i don't know how to implement this functionality of pointing the compass .Can any help me out .

```
CLLocationDirection direction = newHeading.magneticHeading;
double radians = -direction / 180.0 * M_PI;
//For Rotate Niddle
CGFloat angle = RadiansToDegrees(radians);

double angletothelocation=[self bearingToLocation:destinationLocation];

[self rotateArrowView:arrowView degrees:(angle+radianangle)];
```

But i am getting the wrong direction.Can any one suggest me a method to do it?
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Our app has exactly this feature you want. Your code differs a bit, but I think you are missing the orientation fix:

```
self.arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(toRadian((headingFloat+angle) + orientationCorrection));
```

Where orientation correction is:

```
- (int)fixOrientation {
    switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            return 0;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            return 90;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return 270;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            return 180;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't post my whole project. I want to share the code, but it's very close to what you are doing, except that I call various other stuff .. So, you will be lost in my code. Please try this, and tell me if it doesn't work. I will help you till we make your code work together.

Comment: I have tried this method then also its showing to the same direction